# Why is mean [nw:clustering-coefficient] of turtles showing zero?

Tags: netlogo

I have the following network set up:

```
extensions [nw]
breed [agents agent]
agents-own [status         
             
]
to setup

  clear-all
  ask patches [
  set pcolor white
  ]

  nw:generate-preferential-attachment agents links 100 1 [  set shape "person"
  
 setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  set status random 2
    ifelse status = 0 [set status -1][set status 1]
    ifelse status = 1 [set color green] [set color red] ]

      
  display
 output-print nw:mean-path-length
  output-print mean [ nw:clustering-coefficient ] of agents
 output-print mean [nw:betweenness-centrality ] of agents
 output-print mean [ count my-links ] of agents
  output-print count links

reset-ticks
end
```

The mean of the clustering-coefficient always shows zero (other reports show figures that make sense). If I try to show the c-c of an individual turtle I also get zero. Do I need to use a link breed rather than just 'link' in establishing the network? I tried running this with an undirected-link breed and it made no difference.

Am I missing something? The c-c should be >0 right?

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I am not too well versed with networks so I might be wrong here.
The clustering coefficient is a measure for how many of your link-neighbors are also link-neighbors of one another. The way you make your network however (preferential attachment with a single link) simply does not generate a network where your neighbors are ever neighbor to one another, hence the clustering coefficient of every turtle is 0. For example `nw:generate-preferential-attachment agents links 100 2` does generate a few instances where you get three turtles all connected to one another so here you will have a higher clustering coefficient

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm going to have to research this a bit. My understanding of a pa network is that each new node (agent here) would link to 1 existing node. Therefore each node has a neighbor which has potentially a number of links to other nodes. Additionally the new node could be linked to by nodes added subsequently. Therefore I do not follow why just having a new node form 1 link at the time of creation would not lead to neighbors with multi-links - but changing to 2 links clearly solves that.

Comment: It took me  a while to understand the logic : with the pa network each new node (A) links to 1 existing node (B). Thus at this point A only has one neighbor and so northing upon which to calculate a c-c. The existing node B might have a number of nodes but by a similar argument they are unlikely to be linked to each other.